# Unable to paint an array of objects onto a panel in Java

Tags: java, swing, arraylist, jframe, jpanel

The Program is simple enough. I'm trying to get 3-10 random looking faces to print on a panel in a frame in Java. The problem is the faces won't print on the panel. I'm pretty new to this so I'm not sure what I've mucked up, and I've been trying to find a solution to my problem for a while. Any help?

```
//Leonard 
//Random Face Drawer(3-10)
//Last Modified: 10/6/18

import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Random;

//Main Class
public class FaceDraw {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int width = 900;
        int height = 600;
        Random rand = new Random();
        ArrayList<Face> myFaceList = new ArrayList<Face>();
        for( int i = 1; i < (rand.nextInt(8)+3); i ++) {
            myFaceList.add(new Face(rand.nextInt(width-50)+50,rand.nextInt(height-50)+50,rand.nextInt(101),rand.nextInt(101)));
            System.out.print(myFaceList);
        }
        FaceFrame myFaceFrame = new FaceFrame(myFaceList, width, height);
        myFaceFrame.setVisible(true);
    }
}

class OvalDraw extends Oval{
    public OvalDraw () {
        super(0,0,0,0);
    }
    public OvalDraw (int positionXIn, int positionYIn, int widthIn, int heightIn) {
        super(positionXIn, positionYIn, widthIn, heightIn);
    }
    public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        g.drawOval(getPositionX(),getPositionY(),getWidth(),getHeight());
        System.out.format("OvalDraw.paintComponent(x = %d, y = %d, w = %d, h = %d)", getPositionX(),getPositionY(),getWidth(),getHeight());
    }
}
//Face Class, extends from OvalDraw makes the face  
class Face extends OvalDraw {
    private OvalDraw eye1;
    private OvalDraw eye2;
    private Random smile;
    private int smileStatus;

    public Face () {
        super(0, 0, 0, 0);
        eye1 = new OvalDraw(0,0,0,0);
        eye2 = new OvalDraw(0,0,0,0);
        smileStatus = smile.nextInt(2);
    }
    public Face (int positionXIn, int positionYIn, int widthIn, int heightIn) {
        super(positionXIn, positionYIn, widthIn, heightIn);

        // variables to set my eyes to be the same size but in two different spots on the same y axis
        int eyeHeight = heightIn/12;
        int eyeWidth = widthIn/10;
        int eye1PositionX = positionXIn + positionXIn/3;
        int eyePositionY = positionYIn + positionYIn/12;
        int eye2PositionX = eye1PositionX + (positionXIn/3)*2;


        eye1 = new OvalDraw(eye1PositionX,eyePositionY,eyeWidth,eyeHeight);
        eye2 = new OvalDraw(eye2PositionX,eyePositionY,eyeWidth,eyeHeight);
    }
    public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        super.paintComponent(g);
        eye1.paintComponent(g);
        eye2.paintComponent(g);
        if(smileStatus == 0) {
            g.drawArc(getPositionX(), getPositionY() + getHeight()/2, getWidth(), getHeight(), 45, 90);
        }else if(smileStatus == 1){
            g.drawArc(getPositionX(), getPositionY() + getHeight()/2, getWidth(), getHeight(), 45, 90);
        }else{
            g.drawArc(getPositionX(), getPositionY() + getHeight()/2, getWidth(), getHeight(), 45, 90);
        }
    }
}
class FacePanel extends JPanel{
    private ArrayList<Face> FaceList;
    public void setFaceList(ArrayList<Face> FaceListIn) {
        FaceList = FaceListIn;
    }

    //draw panel
    FacePanel(){
        super();
        assert false:"unexpected error...(shape draw panel)";
    }
    FacePanel(ArrayList<Face> FaceListIn){
        setFaceList(FaceList);
    }
    public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        super.paintComponent(g); 
        for (Face oD : FaceList) {
            oD.paintComponent(g);
        }
    }
}
class FaceFrame extends JFrame{
    private FacePanel myFacePanel;

    public FaceFrame(ArrayList<Face> faceListIn, int width, int height) {
        setBounds(100,100,900,600);
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        FacePanel myFacepanel = new FacePanel(faceListIn);
    }

}



//Main class for my Shapes
abstract class Shape {
    //setting of position

    //positioning for x
    public final void setPositionX(int positionXIn) { 
        positionX = positionXIn; 
    }
    public final int getPositionX() { 
        return positionX; 
    }
    private int positionX;

    //positioning for y
    public final int getPositionY() {
         return positionY;
        }
    public final void setPositionY(int positionYIn) { 
        positionY = positionYIn; 
    }
    private int positionY;

    //The Width of the Shape
    public final void setWidth(int widthIn) { 
        width = OneOrGreater(widthIn); 
    }
    public final int getWidth() { 
        return width; 
    }
    private int width;

    //The Height of the Shape
    public final void setHeight(int heightIn) { 
        height = OneOrGreater(heightIn); 
    }
    public final int getHeight() { 
        return height; 
    }
    private int height;

    //function for shape
    public Shape() {
        this(0,0,0,0);
    }

    public Shape(int positionXIn, int positionYIn, int widthIn, int heightIn) {
        setPositionX(positionXIn);
        setPositionY(positionYIn);
        setWidth(widthIn);
        setHeight(heightIn); 
    }

    protected static int OneOrGreater(int valueIn) {
        assert valueIn>=1:"Shape parameter is unexeptedly less than 1.";
        int returnValue = valueIn;
        if (valueIn < 1) {
            returnValue = 1;
        }
        return returnValue;
    }

    //strings
    public String toString() {
        return String.format("positionX=%d, positionY=%d, width=%d, height=%d", positionX, positionY, getWidth(), getHeight());
    }

    abstract public double CalcArea();
    abstract public double CalcPerimeter();
}

//The Rectangle class that inherits from Shape
class Rectangle extends Shape {
    public Rectangle() {
        this(0,0);
    }

    public Rectangle(int widthIn, int heightIn) {
        setWidth(widthIn);
        setHeight(heightIn);
    }

    public Rectangle(int positionXIn, int positionYIn, int widthIn, int heightIn) {
        super(positionXIn, positionYIn, widthIn, heightIn);
    }

    //calculating area for rectangle is base * height 
    public double CalcArea() {
        return getWidth() * getHeight();
    }

    //calculating rectangle perimeter is 2(width+height)
    public double CalcPerimeter() {
        return getWidth() + getWidth() + getHeight() + getHeight();
    }
}

//Class for Oval that inherits from Shape
class Oval extends Shape {
    Oval () {
        super();
    }

    Oval(int positionXIn, int positionYIn, int widthIn, int heightIn) {
        super(positionXIn, positionYIn, widthIn, heightIn);
    }

    //Calculating area of oval with oval formula
    public double CalcArea() {
        return Math.PI * (getWidth()/2) * (getHeight()/2);
    }

    //The perimeter of an oval is 2 pi * square root of ((a^2+b^2)/2)
    public double CalcPerimeter() {
        double a = getWidth() / 2.0;
        double b = getHeight() / 2.0;
        double perimeter =2*Math.PI*Math.sqrt((Math.pow(a,2)+Math.pow(b,2))/2);
        return perimeter;
    }
}
```

Comment: What have you tried so far?  And are you getting any error messages or anything?

Comment: I haven't really tried anything, checked to make sure my arraylist wasn't getting messed up somehow through the program somehow. Other than that nothing I'm not experienced enough to know what I could do. I have no errors, the program runs, just no faces.

Comment: Where's `Oval`? `private static ArrayList<Face> FaceList;` is dangerous (and some what short sighted) and should be avoided

Comment: I added Oval, forgot that was a part of this too. As for private static ArrayList<Face> FaceList; that could very well be a big problem. As soon as I remove the static and change it to just private it gives me an error two lines below it. "Cannot make a static reference to the non-static field FaceList".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
class FaceFrame extends JFrame {

    private FacePanel myFacePanel;

    public FaceFrame(ArrayList<Face> faceListIn, int width, int height) {
        setBounds(100, 100, 900, 600);
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        FacePanel myFacepanel = new FacePanel(faceListIn);
    }

}
```

Adding `myFacepanel` to the `JFrame` might be a good start...

```
public FaceFrame(ArrayList<Face> faceListIn, int width, int height) {
    setBounds(100, 100, 900, 600);
    setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    FacePanel myFacepanel = new FacePanel(faceListIn);
    // This might be a good place to start
    add(myFacepanel);
}
```

## ... next problem ...

```
FacePanel(ArrayList<Face> FaceListIn){
    setFaceList(FaceList);
}
```

Your assigning `FaceList` to itself (you're not using `FaceListIn`).

I'd get rid of the `static` and update the code...

```
class FacePanel extends JPanel {

    private ArrayList<Face> FaceList;

    public void setFaceList(ArrayList<Face> FaceListIn) {
        FaceList = FaceListIn;
    }

    //draw panel
    FacePanel() {
        super();
    }

    FacePanel(ArrayList<Face> FaceListIn) {
        setFaceList(FaceListIn);
    }

    public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        super.paintComponent(g);
        for (Face oD : FaceList) {
            oD.paintComponent(g);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Ahh, I see where the error was coming from due to making it static. However, adding add(myFacePanel); Just gives me java.lang.NullPointerException

Comment: You have helped me out so much, I was quite confused before, haven't worked with java at like all. Thank you so much!